# C++ compressing using lz4, compressed information not as expected

Tags: c++, file, compression, fstream, lz4

I'm using lz4 on mac and doing an experiment to compress a string (named str) in my program.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "lz4.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char str[] = "10100100010000100000100000010000000100000000100000000010000000000";
    size_t len = sizeof(str);
    char* target = new char[len];
    int nCompressedSize = LZ4_compress_default((const char *)(&str), target, len, len);

    ofstream os("lz4.dat",ofstream::binary);
    os.write(target, nCompressedSize);
    os.close();
    delete[] target;
    target = 0;

    ifstream is( "lz4.dat", ifstream::binary );
    is.seekg (0,is.end);
    size_t nCompressedInputSize = is.tellg();
    is.clear();
    is.seekg(0,ios::beg);

    //Read file into buffer
    char* in = new char[nCompressedInputSize];
    int32_t n=is.read(in,nCompressedSize);
    cout<<"Byte number:"<<nCompressedSize<<",file size:"<<n<<",bytes read:"<<in<<endl;
    is.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Run this program, I checked the "lz4.dat" file:

```
$ls -lrt lz4.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 x  staff  34  7 15 14:50 lz4.dat
```

It's 34 bytes, OK, but the program output is:

```
Byte number:34,file size:1,bytes read:@1010
```

Very strange, seems the file size received is 1 byte, and I actually output some randome @1010. Why my "is.tellg()" didn't get correct file length?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked nCompressedSize? Is it larger than 34 bytes? THe point is that the compressed string might be longer than the initial string if the string is small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifstream::read()` doesn't return the bytes read. It returns a reference to `*this`, which has `operator bool()`, which is used in case, I think. So you in `n`, you get whether the operation was succeeded.

Output seems to be completely fine, it is the beginning of the compressed data. I think there is only several bytes printed, because it contains a terminating zero. And it resembles your input, because lz4 puts literals into the stream verbatim (lz4 doesn't have an entropy encoding)